# Questions on the the assembly language about the indirect load/store

Tags: assembly

I am a beginner for the assembly language. I am confused about the code below:

```
0x0100: load #varstr R2
        store R2 varptr
        jump whilebool

loop:   load varptr R3
        **load R3 R4**
        store R4 0xfff0
        load #'\n' R4
        store R4 0xfff0
        load varptr R3
        load #1 R5
        add R3 R5 R3
        store R3 varptr

whilebool:  load varptr R1
        **load R1 R2**
        jumpnz R2 loop
        halt

varptr:     block 1
varstr:     block #"Hello"
```

I don't understand the point on the contents which are bold. I think for the first place, it can just be written as load varptr R3 and  store R3 0xfff0

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have specified the architecture.

Guessing from the fact that your title says `indirect load/store` I would say that `load R3 R4` does not simply do `R4 = R3`, instead it does `R4 = memory[R3]` since that is called an indirection. If that is the case, you obviously can't omit this step.

`varptr` is initially set up to point to the beginning of `varstr`. Your loop first loads this pointer into `R3` then loads the character referenced into `R4`. The character is then written to address `0xfff0` which I assume is a memory-mapped output device. It prints a newline after each character. The code then increments the `varptr` by one so it points to the next character. Finally, the `whilebool` block checks if the end of the string is reached by checking whether the current character is zero. For this, it needs to dereference the pointer again.

There are many ways to simplify this code, but removing the indirection is not one of them ;)